# Approximating $\pi$ in Binary

Tags: approximation, pi, computational-mathematics

I am interested in creating a Java program that generates digits of $\pi$ (in Binary though). To be clear, the number I'm looking for begins: $11.00100100 \dots$

I am unsure of the most efficient way to generate the number. I have looked at the Wikipedia page for this, and I cannot seem to tell which method would be most efficient. I am looking to generating digits of $\pi$ up to perhaps even the billionth digit, so I am looking for a method that is efficient even for such accurate approximations.

Thank you in advance for any help you might give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to play with the algorithms given under the section "Spigot algorithms", esp. the [Borwein-Pluffe formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula), as it can generate hex digits without memory overhead for previous results.

Answer (score 0):

Generating billions of digits is probably a job best left to the pros, but you might look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80

Comment: Thanks! I have already looked at that Wikipedia page, but I couldn't quite figure out which might be best for my application (besides the ones that were obviously less efficient).

Comment: And perhaps such a task is foolish, but is this not why we have computers to overload?

Comment: See the section "Efficient methods".  The Machin-type formulas are probably easiest to implement, as they only require addition, and multiplication and division by small integers.